# Lisp common elements in a list

Tags: runtime-error, lisp

We've recently started learning Common Lisp in our class. I am trying to implement a function that takes two list and outputs their common elements. We are restricted to using basic functional forms.

```
(defun myCommon(L1 L2)
(cond
    ((null L1) nil) ;;check if the first list is empty
    ((null L2) nil) ;;check if the second list is empty
    ((eq (car L1) (car L2)) ((car L1) (myCommon (cdr L1) L2))) 
    (t (myCommon (cdr L1) L2)) ;;if they are not the same, recurse myCommon with L1 as (cdr L1)
)
```

)

My problem is that I cannot understand why it results as a type error (offending datum: (CAR L1)). It seems to be expecting a function type as far as I could make sense of it.

> Error: TYPE-ERROR :DATUM (CAR L1) :EXPECTED-TYPE FUNCTION
>   Fast links are on: do (si::use-fast-links nil) for debugging
>   Signalled by COND.
>   TYPE-ERROR :DATUM (CAR L1) :EXPECTED-TYPE FUNCTION
>
> Broken at COND.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is due to the fact that in the second branch of the `cond`, the expression which is evaluated when the condition about the equality of the two `car`s is true is: `((car L1) (myCommon (cdr L1) L2)))`.

Here you have a list with two elements `((car L1) (myCommon...))` in a position where a **form** is required (that is list with a structure like `(function argument1 argument2 ...)`). So the system gives an error since `(car l1)` is not a function. What I suppose you want to do is to **produce** a new list with those two arguments, which could be obtained for instance by “consing” them, like in `(cons (car L1) (myCommon...))`, so this is your function rewritten:

```
(defun myCommon(L1 L2)
  (cond ((null L1) nil) ;;check if the first list is empty
        ((null L2) nil) ;;check if the second list is empty
        ((eq (car L1) (car L2)) (cons (car L1) (myCommon (cdr L1) L2))) 
        (t (myCommon (cdr L1) L2)))) ;;if they are not the same, recurse myCommon with L1 as (cdr L1)
```

Note that if you try this function for instance on: `(mycommon '(1 2 3) '(1 2 3 4)` you will find that the answer is `(1)` and not `(1 2 3)`. This is because you are “consuming” only the first argument (by recurring on it with `(cdr L1)`). So, you need to correct the function “consuming” also the second argument when necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand the cause of the error now. Could you elaborate a bit more on "consuming" the second argument? For the recursion, wouldn't L2 be the second argument?

Comment: I remained vague since I didn't understand what is the purpose of the function: “outputs their common elements”: the elements of the lists are sorted? The two lists have a common prefix? Or you want just do the intersection of the two lists? Please specify at least some example of input and output so that I can understand the problem.

Comment: It is suppose to be an intersection of two list (i.e (myCommon '(a e f g) '(p a e t) => (a e). I see now that my function if flawed since as it is now I'm always comparing against the first element of L2 which will yield incorrect results. I have a prior function that determines if an element is a member of a list(myMember) and I have been trying to use that.

    ((myMember (car L1) L2) ((car L1) (myCommon(cdr L1) L2))

This is how I have my third line in cond now but I am getting an unexpected end to input stream error but the parenthesis all checks out.

Comment: Then it should be better if you post a new question to SO, specifying the task the you have to solve, the function that you have defined, and the error(s) that you cannot solve. Note also the using a good editor that manages the parentheses (like Emacs with SLIME) saves you a lot of work in checking the correctness of the syntax (and indent automatically the program so that it is more understandable. Note also that `((car L1) (myCommon(cdr L1) L2)) ` in the new function is the same error as the previous one.